# How to access/detect particular activity variable from another android application Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Suppose, 
I have two separate android projects.
first project is A, second project is B.
Project A have many activity class such as a, aa, aaa, aaaa etc.
also Project B  have many activity class such as b, bb, bbb, bbb etc.
aa activtiy contains on project A.

```
Boolean foo;

if (request.getParameter("foo") == null)
    foo = false;
else
    foo = true;
```

somehow, i need detect foo variable of activity aa is true or false from project B. 
 
in the situation, i try like this, from project B, inside bb activity class

```
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(
                    "com.example.a");
            if (intent != null) {
                // detect project A
            } else {
// detect project B
}
```

I detect project A install or not successfully.

But i want to detect foo is true or false of aa activity from Project B.
How to is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use Context.createPackageContext() to instantiate a package for Project B's .apk in which you are interested in.
 
`Context projectAContext = this.createPackageContext("packageName", Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);` 
If it is signed with the same cert as Project A, AND both APKs are using the same shared user ID, then you can use the flag to load its code into your process, allowing you to get the ClassLoader from the context and instantiate classes that you want.

For example:

```
Class projectAClass = projectAContext .getClassLoader().loadClass("packageName.className");
```

Once you have a projectAClass (which has foo), you may invoke a method who returns value of foo.

```
projectAClass.getMethod("getfoo", noparams).invoke(projectAClass.newInstance(), null);
```